# Make query faster. Php Sql in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, performance

In my website, i store and fetch basketball player's stats. Now it uses the code below, but since there are 11 attribute stats for each player, it needs 132 queries for each team, so 264 queries hust for the teams. With debug i saw that in needs 0,5 sec, for each query that is to much time for my site.

1. Do the records in the database affect the execution time? I had 2m records, but now that i have 1.m records, i do not see much of a difference.
2. Is there any better way for this code to be written to speed up queries?

   $output .= '';
   $output.='';
   $output .= '';
           $output .= ''.__('Add Event','leagueengine').'';
           $output .= '';

   ```
   $output .= '</tr>';
   $output.="<tr><td></td></tr>";
   $output.="<tr><td colspan='2'>".__('Home Team','leagueengine')."</td>";

            $events = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_leagueengine_data WHERE data_type = 'event' ORDER BY sort_order ASC, data_value ASC");
            //$events_count=0;
           foreach($events as $event) {
                   $output.="<th><center><small>$event->data_value</small></center></th>"; 
                   // $events_count++;
           }
               $output.="</tr>";   
           $t_p=count ($homeplayers2);
           if($t_p){
                   foreach($homeplayers2 as $homeplayer){

                       $output.="<tr>";
                           $output.="<td colspan='2'>".leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($homeplayer->player_id,'data_value')."</td>";
                            foreach($events as $event){
                                $evcount = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT count(*) as total_events FROM $table2 WHERE match_id='$mid' AND player_id='$homeplayer->player_id' AND event_id='$event->id'" );
                                $total= $evcount[0]->total_events;

                                   $output.="<td><input type='text' name=hm-$homeplayer->player_id-$event->id value='$total'/></td>";
                            }
                       $output.="</tr>";
                   }
           }
           else{ $output.="<tr><td colspan='12'>No player attending this match</td></tr>";}


   $output.="<tr><td></td></tr>";
   ```

   $output.='';

Comment: u should never do SQL in Loops. try to use 1 SQL Statement and just call the result wit the index u Need.

Comment: Have you indexed your tables?

Comment: No i havent indexed.I add and update events table about 10 times a day through the plugin. The great problem is when counting each total events for each player

Comment: If you're doing queries like that, you should index.. No matter how much you update and insert. (almost)

Comment: This is extremely bad, you're making a call to SQL per iteration of your loop giving you n+1 queries...in short very bad!   You could optimise this by running a subquery to get the count for each team as its own column...finally you definitely need to index your tables, you'll notice a significant performance increase!

Comment: As i am not familiar with index, do i have to reindex every time i add events? And in my table there is tournament_id-match_id,player_team,player_id,and event_id. Which column do you think it should be indexed? Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

You do not need this many queries, in fact you only need one.

Running queries inside of a loop is a clear indication that you're doing something highly inefficient. Especially so if these queries are `SELECT` queries.
The proper tool in this case is using a single `SELECT` with `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` on the other tables to retrieve the associated data.

Here's a quick, and incomplete, example of how you can do this:

```
<?php
$output .= '<form action="" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:20px;">';
$output .= '<table class="form">';
$output .= '<tr>';
$output .= '<th colspan="12">' . __ ('Add Event', 'leagueengine') . '</th>';
$output .= '<th colspan="2"  style="text-align:center;"><input style="vertical-align:middle;" type="submit" name="add_home_event_to_match" class="button-primary" value="' . __ ('Submit', 'leagueengine') . '" /></th>';

$output .= '</tr>';
$output .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
$output .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>" . __ ('Home Team', 'leagueengine') . "</td>";

// Query the database for all relevant details using JOINs.
$query = <<<QueryString
    SELECT ld.*, count(*) as total_events FROM wp_leagueengine_data AS ld
    INNER JOIN results AS r ON r.match_id=ld.id AND player_id={$homeplayer->player_id} AND event_id={$event->id}
    WHERE data_type = 'event' ORDER BY sort_order ASC, data_value ASC
QueryString;

$events = $wpdb->get_results ($query);

// This is used to keep track of the events, so that we can print out the header when this changes.
$oldEvent = 0;

// $events_count=0;
foreach ($events as $event) {
    // Print the event header if we have a new event ID.
    if ($oldEvent != $event->id) {
        $output .= "</tr><tr><th><center><small>{$event->data_value}</small></center></th></tr><tr>";
        $oldEvent = $event->id;
    }

    // $events_count++;

    $t_p = count ($homeplayers2);

    if ($t_p) {
            $output .= "<tr>";
            $output .= "<td colspan='2'>" . $event->player_id . "</td>";
            $total = $event->total_events;
            $output .= "<td><input type='text' name='hm-{$event->player_id}-{$event->id}' value='$total'/></td>";
            $output .= "</tr>";
    } else {
        $output .= "<tr><td colspan='12'>No player attending this match</td></tr>";
    }
}

$output .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
$output .= '</form>';
```

Comment: Is anyone of you working as freelancer maybe? I would preger Christian solution. I need to get this done, but i do not believe i can accomplish that..

Comment: @GiwrgosRad: I have worked as a freelancer, but I'm afraid I don't have the time nor capacity to undertake this for you. I wish you the best of luck, and I'm glad to see that you realize your limitations. Should help you make you a really great developer, should you decide to persue this path further. :)